# Hovereffect with text on image not working

Tags: css, image, animation, hover

I'm a very basic coding person that needs something to work, but IDK how. I have a website where I have 4 images. When you hover over those img they become slightly darker, but I wish there was a way to show some text as well (preview of how it should work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUW8i.jpg)

Here's the link to my GitHub code: https://github.com/Ezzol/HCI-Portfolio

Can anyone explain to me what I need to do to add that hovereffect you can see in my design at the imgur link?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like html and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the CSS `hover` event. Here's a good example on how to do that.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp

Comment: The problem with this is that the display block won't work with my flexbox it seems. Whenever I try something like this it doesn't position it correctly because otherwise the images won't scale correctly, if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to use javascript as well, and do an EventListener to tell when it is being hovered over, and then use .style to change it, for example:

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var exampleimg = document.getElementById("exampleimg");
exampleimg.addEventListener("mouseover", examplechange);
exampleimg.addEventListener("mouseout", examplechangeback);
function examplechange(event)
{
 text.style.display = "block";
}

function examplechangeback()
{
  text.style.display = "none";
}
```

add a h1/h2/h3/p element to your page, and give it the id "text" then style it how you want and set the display to none.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but then the text shows next to the image instead of on top of the image. It changes the shape of the image this way. I think it has to do with the flexbox I'm using, but idk how to change that. Link: https://ezzol.github.io/HCI-Portfolio/